# How do you defeat the bounty hunter in full of stars?

Tags: full-of-stars

In the ios game Full of Stars, after you reach the slave destination, you get pursued by a bounty hunter who wants the slaves you're carrying (if you disagreed to give them up). Is there any faster way or technique to defeat this guy? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My strategy is stocking up iridium. What I do is make sure I have like 5000 iridium stored. I always either repair my shield to 20 or 50% because they can only bring down your shield to zero percent, then they have to attack again to kill your crew. Here’s a list:

- Stock up iridium(as much as you can! This can be done easier by getting it in Riftinity!)
- Don’t fill your shield all the way
- Always use main cannon as soon as it’s ready. In bad situations use iridium to make it fire right away. But remember it takes 4 turns to recharge. Main cannon does upwards to 40% damage.
- Rapid gun fire is priority. This is why you need iridium. They do up to 20% damage.
- If all else fails, repair your shield to 20%, and flee in the normal way.
- If all else fails but you have resources to spare, use 10 iridium crystals to launch torpedos. Only in emergencies! I don’t know how much damage it does, but emergency only!!